# I there anyway to define a dict in jsoncschema?

Tags: javascript, json, schema, jsonschema

I am trying to define the schema for an `object` type. Is there a way to allow any property name, but restrict all the property values to adhere to some schema. This way I can allow any `key` and ensure all the `values` are of the same structure/type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `additionalProperties` keyword can be either a boolean or a schema.

If it's a schema, then that schema must apply to any properties that don't match either `properties` or `patternProperties`.  Therefore, if your keys can be anything, your schema is just:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {"type": "integer"}
}
```

You'd need to use `patternProperties` if you want to restrict the keys - for example, lower-case alphabetic only:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-z]+$": {"type": "object"}
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Since you want to allow *any* property name, `additionalProperties` is the best solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `patternProperties` does what I want.

I can simply do

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "*": { "type": "integer" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

to allow any key, and restrict all values to be an integer.

Comment: Not quite correct - that regular expression is invalid, and you're better off using `additionalProperties` anyway.